# Can we use Yii2 for Web application and Webservice(Rest) together

Tags: yii2

I'm new to Yii2. I need to know how can we use both website part and its web-service(rest) in single application.

Please help me to elaborate with file and folder structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can ;)

Have a look at this blog post, which describes a full working rest api based upon the advanced app, which comes with yii2:

http://budiirawan.com/setup-restful-api-yii2/

Source:
https://github.com/deerawan/yii2-advanced-api